# Copy and paste bar icons not shown in Action Items bar pre lollipop (5.0)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, copy-paste, android-actionmode

I've been experiencing this weird problem.

Copy and paste icons do not show up in my apps action items bar pre lollipop.

I enable the copy and paste like this:

```
 mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Screeenshots attached:

[image: Lollipop]

Copy and paste bars not shown: only white space

[image: Pre lollipop]

My theme is in styles is : Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Help appreciated from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle use last version AppCompat library

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

And your activity need extends of AppCompatActivity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: No, is AppCompatActivity and test.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your compat library to 22.2.0, it solves the problem for me.

In build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```